# extracting data from 2 xml tags(opening and ending) using libxml2 xpath

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

This is the tag in XML

```
<content>The Avengers</content>
```

I want to take out "The Avengers" from the tag using xpath from libxml2 in `C++`

Here is my code

```
xmlXPathObject * xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression( (xmlChar*)"/content", xpathCtx );
if ( xpathObj == NULL ) throw "failed to evaluate xpath";
for(int i=0;i<=0; i++)
{
    xmlNode *node = NULL;
    if ( xpathObj->nodesetval && xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeTab )
    {
        node = xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeTab[i];
        std::cout << "Found the node we want" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        throw "failed to find the expected node";
    }

    xmlAttr *attr = node->properties;
    while ( attr )
    {
        std::cout << "Attribute name: " << attr->name << "  value: " << attr->children->content << std::endl;
        attr = attr->next;
    }
    xmlSetProp( node, (xmlChar*)"age", (xmlChar*)"3" );
}
```

Its work fine and reached easily at content tag but not showing the data between the tag

RESULT

```
<content age="3">The Avengers</content>
```

but in console its shows nothing 
Found the node we want
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [facing difficulty to reading complex xml file using libxml2 in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562518/facing-difficulty-to-reading-complex-xml-file-using-libxml2-in-c)

Comment: this is my another question dude..

Comment: Code is the same as far I could spot.

Comment: i want to get "The avengers" string from this little xml tag using xpath from libxml2 how to get it simple is that ...

Comment: OK, then it's probably a duplicate of [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363380/libxml2-can%C2%B4t-get-content-from-node).